# In React : how to get the value of variable from another function component

Tags: reactjs, variables, react-props, react-context

how to get the value of changing variable from another function component in React **(Inverse relation of parent elemnts between the two component : the variable exists in child component and i want to get its value in parent component)**

I have struggled with this issue, i used chat gpt and many research in google but always i found the classic example between Parent and Child component , to understand my case here is my Code of 2 Components : **Login.js** and **App.js**. My target is to get the value of haveAccess in Login.js and use it in App.js . Make sure that its value in Login.js is worken (i have test that in console and it works) but in App.js it's undefined. For this I need your Help , and thank you in advance :

**// Login.js** (i have import all necessary elements)

```
// Create a context
export const MyContext =React.createContext();
const Login = () => {
  //----------------
  const auth = useAuth()
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const location = useLocation()
  const redirectPath = location.state?.path || '/'

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState('');
  const [user, setUser] = useState({name :'', email : '',role :''});
  let haveAccess= true;
  

  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value)
  };

  const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };


  const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try{
      const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    })
    if (response.ok) {
      const { user, access_token } = await response.json();
      // Store the user and access_token in state or local storage
      console.log(user, access_token);
            
            auth.login(user)
            if (user.role === 'user') {
              haveAccess = false;
              console.log(haveAccess);
            }
            navigate(redirectPath, '/dashboard', {replace : true}); // Redirect to the dashboard page
          console.log('Login successful');
          console.log(user.role);

        } else {
          // Authentication failed, display error message
          setError('login or password incorrect !');
        }
      }catch (error) {
          console.error('An error occurred:', error);
      }
  };
 
 

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={haveAccess}>
    <div  className='container login'>
      <h1>Login Page</h1>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='g-3 container' >
            <div class="">
                <label ><b>Email</b></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value={email} onChange={handleEmailChange}  aria-describedby="textHelp" placeholder="Enter login" />
            </div>
            <div class=" ">
                <label><b>Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" value={password} onChange={handlePasswordChange}  placeholder="Password" />
            </div><br />
            <div className=''>          
              <Button className='form-control' type="submit" variant="primary" >Login</Button>
            </div>
            </form>
            {error && <p style={{color:'red'}}>{error}</p>}

    </div>
    
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

**// App.js**---------------------------------------------------------------

```
 export default function App() {
 const haveAccess = useContext(MyContext);




 const Menu = ()=>{
   if (useAuth().user ){
     return (<><SideNavBar />
     <Header /></>);
     
   }
 } 
 
 }
 
 return (  
   
         <div className='app'>
     
         <AuthProvider>
          
      <Menu />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route exact path='/' element={<RequireAuth>< Dashboard /></RequireAuth>}/>

          <Route exact path='/Dashboard' element={<RequireAuth>{haveAccess}</RequireAuth>}/>
          <Route exact path='/Customer' element={<RequireAuth><Customer haveAccess={haveAccess}/></RequireAuth>}/>
          <Route exact path='/Product' element={<RequireAuth><Product haveAccess={haveAccess}/>    </RequireAuth>}/>

          <Route exact path='/Report/:claim_id' element={<RequireAuth><Report haveAccess={haveAccess}/>
          <Route exact path='*' element="error 404"/>
      
      </Routes>
  </AuthProvider>  
    </div>
      
   
   
 );
}
```

I tried the code appove and i exepect that when i logged the value of haveAccess change to false if the user logged has the role 'user', so when i test the value of haveAccess in file Login.js it works but in file App.js its undefined , so i want to get just the value of haveAccess that exists in Login.js and use it in App.js

Comment: Either pass the shared value down as a prop and hoist it up to the App, use a context, or Redux toolkit. React is declarative, so data typically flows downward, not up. A callback function can give another component to the state of an internal component as well.

Comment: but i am bot calling the App in Login.js so how to pass the value in the App props ?